# Select feature parts and vertices as rows

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, multipart, arcgis-10.7, st-geometry

I have a Oracle 18c SDE.ST_GEOMETRY FC that has **multi-part** polylines.

I want to select the parts and vertices as individual rows in a query:

[image]

Since we don't have a [GetVertices()](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-ideas/getvertices-function-in-st-geometry/idi-p/1099658) function in [SDE.ST_GEOMETRY](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/a-quick-tour-of-sql-functions-used-with-st-geometry.htm), how can I do that?

Comment: Related SDO_GEOMETRY solution: [Select vertices, including multi-part number](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386569/select-vertices-including-multi-part-number).

Comment: And another sdo_geometry solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076942/5576771

Answer (score 0):

This query seems to work.

It's rather complicated. But without a GetVertices() function, I'm not sure how else to do it. Other than getting the vertices as WKT and somehow parsing them out as rows -- which seems like it would be messy and fragile.

```
with 
      fc as (select * from my_owner.my_fc),
fc_parts as (select 
                 asset_id, part_num, sde.st_geometryn(fc.shape, part_num) as part_shape
             from
                 fc
             cross join    
                 (select level as part_num from dual connect by level <= (select max(sde.st_numgeometries(shape)) from fc)) parts
             where
                 part_num <= sde.st_numgeometries(fc.shape)),
vertices as (select level as vertex_num from dual connect by level <= (select max(sde.st_numpoints(part_shape)) from fc_parts))

select
    asset_id,
    part_num,
    vertex_num,
    sde.st_x(sde.st_pointn(part_shape, vertex_num)) as x,
    sde.st_y(sde.st_pointn(part_shape, vertex_num)) as y
from
    fc_parts
cross join
    vertices
where
    vertices.vertex_num <= sde.st_numpoints(part_shape)
order by
    asset_id,
    part_num,
    vertex_num
```

[image]